# Adding modules in angular-meteor

Tags: angularjs, webpack, module, angular-meteor

I'm developing a web app with angular-meteor (Angular1). This uses webpack as a module bundler. Ever since I started I have found it impossible to inject npm/bower modules to my app module.

I constantly get errors such as:

```
Error: [$injector:nomod] Module xxx is not available! You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it. If registering a module ensure that you specify the dependencies as the second argument.
```

I usually follow official docs which consist of:

- Downloading the npm module
- Including the scripts in my index.html
- Adding the module to my app module

But this always gives the error above.

I then try different techniques such as importing the module at the top of the page using:

```
import exampleModule from 'angular-example-module';
```

and adding exampleModule to my list of modules but nothing seems to work.

I used angular without webpack before and never had this problem. Am I missing something? Is there a particular procedure I don't know about?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer in case anyone else had the same question.

You must import the module in the main javascript file like so:

```
import moduleVariable from '<path-to-module>';
```

and then include the moduleVariable in the dependencies of your application module.